# Crystal report Overflow-x issue in Android Devices

Tags: android, html, css, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am Trying to make a responsive Crystal reports in Visual studio. I given bootstrap table-responsive class to the parent div of Crystal report. In desktop devices its working perfectly. But in android devices table-responsive class is not working. and crystal report width exceeds outside the parent div. scrolls still works but page full scrolls. how can i solve this issue?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="panel-body">
<div style="" class="table-responsive">
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CRViewer" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" EnableParameterPrompt="False" ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True" ToolPanelView="None" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" HasCrystalLogo="False" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" HasToggleParameterPanelButton="False" HasDrilldownTabs="False" HasDrillUpButton="False" HasRefreshButton="True" HasPageNavigationButtons="True" HasPrintButton="True" DisplayToolbar="True" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have a "class="table-responsive"" on a div?

Comment: want to make it responsive